# Git error: ! [rejected] master -> master (non-fast-forward)

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I was updating my project and when tried to upload it to my repository,got the following error:

Already did

> git pull --rebase origin master

```
  ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://*******/production.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

I need to update my website but not able to do so.

EDIT 1:

`> git status` gives:

> rebase in progress; onto cda02b2 You are currently rebasing branch
>   'master' on 'cda02b2'.   (all conflicts fixed: run "git rebase
>   --continue")
>
> nothing to commit, working directory clean

Comment: And what is the output when you called `git pull --rebase origin master`?

Comment: Also: (1) check `git status` (paste the output into the question) and (2) show us the exact `git push` command you ran (these are both in case you are not currently on your own `master`).

Comment: @torek updated and also i ran 'git push origin master'

Comment: @ckruczek output: 'From https://bitbucket.org/**/**
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD

It seems that there is already a rebase-apply directory, and
I wonder if you are in the middle of another rebase.  If that is the
case, please try
        git rebase (--continue | --abort | --skip)
If that is not the case, please
        rm -fr "E:/wamp64/www/laravel/.git/rebase-apply"
and run me again.  I am stopping in case you still have something
valuable there.'

Comment: Well it's totally obvious whats wrong there. Git is already telling you whats the problem. You are in the middle of a rebase. Abort this rebase or finish it and then pull again.

Comment: @ckruczek it worked ty!

Comment: The pull did not end up due to that, :-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As git tells you in the output `It seems that there is already a rebase-apply directory, and I wonder if you are in the middle of another rebase. If that is the case, please try git rebase (--continue | --abort | --skip)` you are in the middle of a rebase.
You first have to abort or continue this rebase by

`git rebase --continue` or

`git rebase --abort`

and then pull again with

`git pull --rebase origin master`

Comment: Thank you buddy. git pull --rebase origin master  work for me.

Answer (score 4):

You must grab the latest change from the the remote before you can push yours. This is what you did with the `git pull --rebase` but it look like it did not work.

Have you verified that the pull was successful?
The you did not had any conflicts?

try this pull without rebase first and see if its working

```
git pull origin master
```

Than you can pull again with --rebase

```
git pull --rebase origin master
```

Then do a push

```
git push origin master
```

Comment: its showing everything up to date after doing push ..but i have made changes to project

Comment: His output is showing it. He is in the middle of a rebase, so nothing will work, neither pull nor push. He has to finish/abort the rebase and then start again by pulling.

Comment: He has updated the question later after i have posted the original answer. as i wrote in the answer the pull did not end up

Comment: Jop I can see it.

Answer (score 1):

I think This problem can have two important reasons
one fetch Repo
Or running one or more **processes** in **Vs-code or tools like source control**
It is better to check it.

If you see

**! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)**

It is better to fetch all Repo :

> **at first**
>
> ```
> git fetch origin master
> ```

now you can see :

**branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD**

> **Next**
>
> ```
> git push -f origin master
> ```